# Animated Line Graph gets ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension at runtime

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, runtime-error, axis

I am trying to create a animated line graph of half lives, the text files referenced look like this:

`decay1.txt`:

```
2000
1000
500
250
125
63
31
16
8
4
0
```

`decay2.txt` is the reverse of `decay1.txt`.

Any help would be appreciated, I believe is most likely something to do with how I am pulling the data from the arrays to create the y axis. The data I enter when prompted is 2000 then 10.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig = plt.figure()
totalnumber_of_nuclei = int(input("Enter total number of nuclei"))#user input totalnumber of nuclei(max y)
TotalTime = int(input("Enter the total time for simulation"))#user input totaltime (max x)
Timescale = np.arange(0., (TotalTime+1.) ,1.)#Time between plots - distance on x between plots
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, TotalTime), ylim=(0, totalnumber_of_nuclei))

def animate(i):
    pullData1 = open("decay1.txt","r").read()
    pullData2 = open("decay2.txt","r").read()
    dataArray1 = pullData1.split("\n")
    dataArray2 = pullData2.split("\n")
    print(int(dataArray1[i]),int(dataArray2[i]))
    y1 = []
    y2 = []
    x = Timescale
    if len(dataArray1[i])>1:
        y1.append(int(dataArray1[i]))
    if len(dataArray2[i])>1:
        y2.append(int(dataArray2[i]))
    ax.plot(x, y1, "b-", marker="o", label="decay1")
    ax.plot(x, y2, "r-", marker="o", label="decay2")

ax.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)
plt.ylabel("Number of Nuclei")#label y axis Number of Nuclei
plt.xlabel("Time")#label x axis Time
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, blit=True)
plt.show()#display graph
```

Error print out:

```
Python 3.3.5 (v3.3.5:62cf4e77f785, Mar  9 2014, 10:35:05) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter total number of nuclei2000
Enter the total time for simulation10

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 475
    warnings.warn("No labelled objects found. "
UserWarning: No labelled objects found. Use label='...' kwarg on individual plots.
2000 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ruari\Documents\School Work\Dropbox\comp 4\tutorial.py", line 30, in <module>
    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000, blit=True)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1067, in __init__
    TimedAnimation.__init__(self, fig, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 913, in __init__
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 591, in __init__
    self._init_draw()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1092, in _init_draw
    self._draw_frame(next(self.new_frame_seq()))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1106, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "C:\Users\Ruari\Documents\School Work\Dropbox\comp 4\tutorial.py", line 24, in animate
    ax.plot(x, y1, "b-", marker="o", label="decay1")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1373, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 304, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 282, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 223, in _xy_from_xy
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
>>>
```

Comment: have you tried printing out `len(x)` and `len(y1)`? As the error message tells you, they have to have the same dimensions.

Comment: @cel i have tried that and length of x is 11 and length of y is 1. Thank you, ill try to find a work around